# Loops without arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

How can I create loop without arrows? (Vertex 7)
Thanks. :)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,baseline=(12.base)]
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,fill=blue!25,minimum size=12pt,inner sep=2pt}}
\node[vertex] (7) at (0,0)  [shape=circle,draw=black] {1};
\node[vertex] (8) at (2,0) [shape=circle,draw=black] {2};
\node[vertex] (9) at (1,-1) [shape=circle,draw=black] {3};
\draw (7) edge[-] (8);
\draw (7) edge[-] (9);
\draw (8) edge[-] (9);
%\nccircle{->}{7,7}{.5cm};
%\EdgeInGraphLoop{8}{8};
%\draw (8) loap[-] (8);
\path (7) edge [loop above] node {} (7);
\path (7) edge [loop] node {} (7);
%\path[-] (8) edge[loop] node[above] {} (8);
\path[-] (8) edge[bend left] (9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Delete `->` from the `tikzpicture` options. Please provide compilable code rather than a fragment, which is much less useful.

Comment: Hi, how can I provide compilable code? I am beginner here.
And it does not work.  (deleting ->) :(

Comment: @Euler: A fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) includes`\documentclass` and required packages, `\begin{document}...\end{document}` that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the arrow from every loop in the preamble as shown in the code.
There are some other small changes from your code that may not be necessary for you. But here is a solution that I have working currently. If you want to have an arrow for some loops only, then add the arrow in the edge definition, as shown.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[shorten >=1pt]
  \tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,fill=blue!25,minimum size=12pt,inner sep=2pt}}
  \tikzset{every loop/.style={}}%removes arrow head from all loops.
  \node[vertex] (7) at (0,0)  [shape=circle,draw=black] {1};
  \node[vertex] (8) at (2,0) [shape=circle,draw=black] {2};
  \node[vertex] (9) at (1,-1) [shape=circle,draw=black] {3};

  \draw [->]  (7) -- (8);
  \draw [->]  (7) -- (9);
  \draw [->]  (8) -- (9);

  \path  (7) edge [->,loop above] node {} (7);%add an arrow to the loop edge
  \path   (7) edge [loop] node {} (7);%there will be no arrow head on this loop.
  \path  (8) edge[->,bend left] (9);%add an arrow to the loop edge
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]